# Memory Based Data Storage

Tags: java, search, collections

I need to load instances of an Account class

```
class Account {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String email;
  ...
}
```

to memory for a quick access. I can use a Java collection class to store the data. I also need to search the data. Since the email address needs to be unique, I am thinking of using map with an email address as the key. That approach won't help if searching the first name and last name are required. I can use filters for searching on first name and last name.

Any better approach?

Comment: You can search HashMaps using the new features in Java 8: https://dzone.com/articles/java-hashmap-search-and-sort

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain several different Java collections or use [in-memory databases](http://www.baeldung.com/java-in-memory-databases) with better searching capabilities or [Java object databases](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+object+database).

However, see also [Coollection](https://github.com/19WAS85/coollection#readme). It's interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I can see the reasons to use several different Java collection classes for the purpose. That, however, is better for read-only operations including search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for stuff, you want to use an indexed collection like Data Store:
https://github.com/jparams/data-store

Example:

```
Store<Account> store = new MemoryStore<>() ;
store.add(new Account("Ed", "Smith", "ed.smith@gmail.com"));
store.add(new Account("Fred", "Smith", "fred.johnson@hotmail.com"));
store.add(new Account("Freda", "Pinto", null));
store.index("firstName", Account::getFirstName);
store.index("lastName", Account::getLastName);
Account ed = store.getFirst("firstName", "Ed");
Account smiths = store.get("lastName", "Smith");
```

With data store you can create case-insensitive indexes and all sorts. If you are doing a lot of lookups, you definitely want to use a library like this.